# Jquery: Display element relative to another

Tags: jquery, css-position

I am trying to display a drop down list using jquery everytime a user clicks on a particular formfield...

At the moment the HTML is as stands

```
// Form field to enter the time an event starts
<div>
  <label for="eventTime"> Event Time </label>
    <input type = "text" name="eventTime" id="eventTime" class="time">
  </label>
</div>

// Form field to enter the time an event finishes
<div>
  <label for="eventEnd"> Event Ends</label>
    <input type = "text" name="eventEnds" id="eventEnds" class="time">
  </label>
</div>
```

And the Jquery looks like so

```
    // Display Time Picker  
$('.time').click(function(){
    var thisTime = $(this);


        var timePicker = '<ul class="timePicker">'
            timePicker += '<li>10.00am</li>'
            timePicker += '<li>11.00am</li>'
            timePicker += '<li>12.00am</li>'
            timePicker += '</ul>'

    $('.timePicker').hide().insertAfter(thisTime);

      //show the menu directly over the placeholder
        var pos = thisTime.offset();

            $(".timePicker").attr({
              top: pos.top
              left: pos.left
            });
             $(".timePicker").show();
                });
```

However, when I click on one the form fields with class time, the timePicker drop down appears, but it always appears in the same location, not next to the form field as I would like.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try applying relative position to the parent element and absolute position to the child, then there's no need to use `pos.left` and `pos.top` maybe 0,0 its fine.

Comment: Yes this works when adding relative positoning to the containing div, wondering what you would do if there where two timePicker form fields within the same containing div? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

have you considered a [time picker plugin](http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/) I'm sure there are more but it sees a shame to re-invent something that already exists

Comment: Yeah, i have looked around for one...I dont like the way that one is displayed, i just want one which displays the time in a drop down list

Comment: actually this one is better http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html